# spark structured streaming avro to avro and custom Sink

Tags: scala, apache-kafka, avro, spark-structured-streaming

Can someone refer me to a good example or sample for writing avro in S3 or any file system? I am using a custom Sink but I would like to pass some properties Map through constructor of the SinkProvider which can be further pass to the Sink, I guess?

Updated Code:

```
val query = df.mapPartitions { itr =>
  itr.map { row =>
    val rowInBytes = row.getAs[Array[Byte]]("value")
    MyUtils.deserializeAvro[GenericRecord](rowInBytes).toString
  }
}.writeStream
  .format("com.test.MyStreamingSinkProvider")
  .outputMode(OutputMode.Append())
  .queryName("testQ" )
  .trigger(ProcessingTime("10 seconds"))
  .option("checkpointLocation", "my_checkpoint_dir")
  .start()

query.awaitTermination()
```

**Sink Provider:**

```
class MyStreamingSinkProvider extends StreamSinkProvider {

  override def createSink(sqlContext: SQLContext, parameters: Map[String, String], partitionColumns: Seq[String], outputMode: OutputMode): Sink = {
    new MyStreamingSink
  }
}
```

**Sink:**

```
class MyStreamingSink extends Sink with Serializable {

  final val log: Logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(classOf[MyStreamingSink])

  override def addBatch(batchId: Long, data: DataFrame): Unit = {
    //For saving as text doc
    data.rdd.saveAsTextFile("path")

    log.warn(s"Total records processed: ${data.count()}")
    log.warn("Data saved.")
  }
}
```

Comment: I created my custom SinkProvider and Sink. I pass the fully qualified class name in the "format" of writeStream and it works for me now. However, I have another question. Is there a way to pass custom properties to SinkProvider? "format" in the writeStream only takes a String as argument.

Comment: See the below code and please suggest if I can pass the property map as constructor from the driver class.

`class MyStreamingSinkProvider(prop: Map[String, String]) extends StreamSinkProvider {

  override def createSink(sqlContext: SQLContext, parameters: Map[String, String], partitionColumns: Seq[String], outputMode: OutputMode): Sink = {
    new MyStreamingSink(prop: Map[String, String])
  }
}`

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. I guess I have moved on from the initial error I posted previously and completely edited my post with the current question @cricket_007

It will be nice to know how to pass custom properties to the SinkProvider.

Comment: any thoughts or suggestions??

Answer (score 3):

You should be able to pass parameters to your custom sink via `writeStream.option(key, value)`:

```
DataStreamWriter writer = dataset.writeStream()
  .format("com.test.MyStreamingSinkProvider")
  .outputMode(OutputMode.Append())
  .queryName("testQ" )
  .trigger(ProcessingTime("10 seconds"))
  .option("key_1", "value_1")
  .option("key_2", "value_2")
  .start()
```

In this case `parameters` in method `MyStreamingSinkProvider.createSink(...)` will contain `key_1` and `key_2`